# problem renaming files with os.rename and my counter

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I'm trying to rename a load of files and using a counter which is loaded into the name.

When I run the script the files in the folder get renamed to start at 02, and not 01.

When i print the counter in the loop it starts at 1.
The folder has 68 files in it.
When count I the length of the list containing the file names before the rename i get 70.
After the script is run there is still 68 files in the folder.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Thanks.

```
import os

path = 'spanish_pages_photos/'
pathContents = os.listdir(path)

pathContents.sort()
counter = 0
list = []
for i in pathContents:
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    os.rename(f'{path}{i}', f'{path}photo_0{counter}.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) is about the content of a directory not only files but also directories. Print also `i` for verification.

I assume your are on an UNIXoide OS and have hidden directories/files. Instead of `os.listdir()` use `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*'))`.